# Back button in react-native-tvos

Tags: react-native, tvos, apple-tv, react-native-tvos

`handleBackPress` doesn't get called when press back menu button in react-native-tvos:

```js
 useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      TVEventControl.enableTVMenuKey();
      props.navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e: any) => {
        if (isTVOS) {
          handleBackPress
        };
      }),
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
      return () => {
        TVEventControl.disableTVMenuKey();
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
      };
    }, []),
  );
```